# How to know which variable contribute the most to the PC component?

Tags: r, pca

Here's my code :

```
mammal.pca_no.corr <- prcomp(PCA_mammal_dataset_no.corr, scale = T)
summary(mammal.pca)
mammal_pca_no.corr$rotation
```

And here's the output:

```
Importance of components:
                          PC1    PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6     PC7     PC8     PC9    PC10
Standard deviation     2.6653 1.4929 0.53917 0.35689 0.31104 0.29074 0.21260 0.12012 0.08043 0.04318
Proportion of Variance 0.7104 0.2229 0.02907 0.01274 0.00967 0.00845 0.00452 0.00144 0.00065 0.00019
Cumulative Proportion  0.7104 0.9333 0.96234 0.97508 0.98475 0.99320 0.99772 0.99917 0.99981 1.00000
                        PC1         PC2          PC3        PC4         PC5        PC6
adult_body_mass_g 0.2898569 -0.70308588 -0.375681954  0.1141424 -0.40480411  0.3219029
longevity_y       0.4473037 -0.01703924  0.509790194  0.7227587 -0.02265857 -0.1298056
adult_svl_cm      0.4151987 -0.42151638 -0.003714323 -0.3193357  0.61382852 -0.4137142
female_maturity_d 0.4521501  0.25324957  0.180901772 -0.2579211  0.24483079  0.7564616
male_maturity_d   0.4497617  0.22521078  0.161112601 -0.4673997 -0.62155166 -0.3409520
weaning_d         0.3698475  0.46135518 -0.735037761  0.2786222  0.11209906 -0.1410220
```

And here's the autoplot:
[image]

Based on the output, I'll probably select PC1 and PC2. For PC2, the most prominent variable is the `adult_body_mass`, but what about PC1? All variables contribute to it relatively equally except for `adult_body_mass` and `weaning_d`. How should I interpret this?

Comment: This seems like more of a statistical question than a programming question - I think it would fit better at stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: The loadings are shown in the table in your summary. The greatest (absolute) loading in PC1 is `female_maturity_d` at 0.4521501, but yes, 4 of your variables have similar loadings in PC1.

Comment: Your results are typical for data in which multiple variables measure some aspect of size so that all or most of the variables correlate with one another (just look at the correlation matrix). This size component is usually the first one and "explains" the most variability in the data. In your case 71% of the variation is explained by PC1 and 22% by PC2.